# Manipulating a list inside a Python dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have this JSON file:

```json
{"809849410283372605": {"wallet": 0, "submitted": [""], "bank": 0}}
```

I'm trying to put strings into the `[""]`.

I've tried this:

```
users[str(user.id)]["submitted"] + 'earnings'
with open("mainbank.json",'w') as f:
   json.dump(users,f)
```

Yet it never works.

Comment: `users[str(user.id)]["submitted"].append('earnings')`

Comment: Or `users[str(user.id)]["submitted"] += ['earnings']`

Comment: @flakes This was the easiest answer, I was wondering if you could post it as a answer. I think it would help a lot of people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual code

```py
users[str(user.id)]["submitted"] + 'earnings'
with open("mainbank.json",'w') as f:
   json.dump(users,f)
```

Won't work because it's not updating anything. Try

```py
# I suppose the + sign is to update the empty string ""
users[str(user.id)]["submitted"].append('earnings')
with open("mainbank.json",'w') as f:
   json.dump(users,f)
```

If you happend to need the submitted info to be filled as a list then try:

```py
# with an empty list
{"809849410283372605": {"wallet": 0, "submitted": [], "bank": 0}}

users[str(user.id)]["submitted"].append('earnings')
with open("mainbank.json",'w') as f:
   json.dump(users,f)
```

If you need to **change** the value of the `""` empty string just use:

```py
users[str(user.id)]["submitted"][0] = 'earnings'
with open("mainbank.json",'w') as f:
   json.dump(users,f)
```

Answer (score 0):

string concatenation with `+` just creates a new string but doesn't save it anywhere. I think, what you're looking for is to `append` to that list:

```py
users[str(user.id)]["submitted"].append("earnings")
```

or alternatively if you want to replace the list of an empty value you could do

```py
# replace list with just a string
users[str(user.id)]["submitted"] = "earnings"

# replace list with other list
users[str(user.id)]["submitted"] = ["earnings"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying just to add an item to that section of the list, use `.append()`, like below

```
users = {"809849410283372605": {"wallet": 0, "submitted": [""], "bank": 0}}
users["809849410283372605"]['submitted'].append("earnings")
print(users)
>{'809849410283372605': {'wallet': 0, 'submitted': ['', 'earnings'], 'bank': 0}}
```

If you want to change the empty quotes to something else, use

```
users = {"809849410283372605": {"wallet": 0, "submitted": [""], "bank": 0}}
users["809849410283372605"]['submitted'][0] = "earnings"
print(users)
{'809849410283372605': {'wallet': 0, 'submitted': ['earnings'], 'bank': 0}}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use something like , which will just replace your '' character

users[str(user.id)]['submitted']=['Earning' if x=='' else x for x in users[str(user.id)]['submitted']]